# how do I use javascript to extract some data into a variable?

Tags: javascript

I need to extract some data

```
<span class="btn btn-orange" 
      style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer;" 
      onclick="javascript:showPixelId(250);" 
      data-mpn-code="7290108862140" 
      data-color="#2695d8" 
      data-initialized="true">Acquista Online</span>
```

I have this code and I want the `7290108862140` to be returned into a javascript variable

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: On which event you want to pass this code?

Comment: There is no specific event. The information is on a product page and I want to extract this numer into a variable so I can use it.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript) for more details. But what is it's use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data to handle:

```
let span = document.getElementBy('btn-orange');
let mpnCode = div1.getAttribute('data-mpn-code');
let color = div1.getAttribute('data-color');
let initialized = div1.getAttribute('data-initialized');
```

or just use it directly. For example:

```
let span = document.getElementBy('btn-orange');
console.log(div1.getAttribute('data-mpn-code'));
console.log(div1.getAttribute('data-color'));
console.log(div1.getAttribute('data-initialized'));
```

//output:

7290108862140

#2695d8

true